# Disable HTTP logging for specific backend in HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

How does one adjust logging level or disable logging altogether for specific backends in HAProxy?

In the example below, both directives "**http-request set-log-level err**" and "**no log**" seem to have no effect - the logs are swamped with lines of successful HTTP status 200 OK records.

```
global
  log /dev/log local0
  log /dev/log local1 notice
```

...

```
defaults
  log global
  mode http

  option httplog
  option dontlognull
```

...

```
backend static
  http-request set-log-level err
  no log
```

Comment: `dontlognormal` might do what you want. Can't be used in the backend section though.

Comment: @wurtel that's correct - `option dontlog-normal` cannot be set at the backend level and impacts all backends linked to a frontend with this option set.

http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4-option%20dontlog-normal

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Courtesy of *meineerde* in `#haproxy` on Freenode:

You can disable logging in the frontend, using the same conditions by which you pick the backend.

```
http-request set-log-level silent if static
use_backend static                if static
```

This must happen in the frontend section, because the logging decision must be made at this stage.